# Text columns in Sketch

Tags: typography, sketch-app, layout

Is it possible to set text in columns like you can in InDesign? I can't find anything online about this.

Comment: If you mean with linked text boxes then no, at the moment it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there isn't anything like that out the box. Something like this sounds like it would be in the [directory of Sketch plugins](https://www.sketchapp.com/extensions/plugins/), but it doesn't look there is one yet.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin for this, called [sketch-text-tools](https://github.com/automat/sketch-text-tools#5), was being developed on GitHub, but it appears to have been abandoned. It says it is compatible with Sketch up through version 43.1.